# Android options do not show in eclipse on updating from ADT 22.3 to 22.6

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

1. I downloaded the Android Development Toolkit (ADT) from Google and I ran it.
2. I then updated some of the android SDk packages like the android versions, repository etc.
3. When I restarted eclipse I got a message saying I had to update the ADT from 22.3 to 22.6
4. After doing this following all the Normal procedure of Install new software > select google repo > select packages > Install > ... > Click ok on unsupported message etc. when I restarted eclipse, all the ADT options are gone and I only see the normal Java perspective. The ADT 22.6 options in the Install new software show as installed.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Cheers!
Gavin.

Comment: check eclipse: Window - Preferences - Android - SDK is present or not. if not present then browse and give SDK path here.

Comment: @maddy: Thank you for your response.
I noted that if I change the main folder name after unzipping the files the SDK stops working. However, if I keep it the same (eg: adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030) it works. I will post the method that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download and extract ADT. Do not change the folder name
2. First update the ADT version from 22.3.x to 22.6.x in the following
   way: HELP > Install New Software > Work with (Android Developer
   Tools Update Site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
   [note the "https"] > Select Developer tools > Next ...
3. Now open SDK Manager and install the android libraries you require.

This is what worked for me. No problems at all.